# 2 rengar and 2 kha'zix

Tags: league-of-legends

What would happen if there were example, in team #1, 1 kha'zix and 1 rengar and then in team #2, 1 kha'zix and 1 rengar. Would this mean that there would be 2 "the hunt is on"? Has anyone ever tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event only occurs when some conditions are met. These are:

- Kha'zix needs 3 evolution points
- Rengar needs a bonetooth necklace with at least 10 stacks
- All Members of the both teams are alive

Now The event can only occur once and it happens to these two who met the conditions first.